# Android NDK pthread context switching

Tags: c++, android-ndk, posix

What is the proper way to context switch pthreads, from my understanding `pthread_yield()` and `sched_yield()` respectively are not available/have no effect when using NDK.

EDIT: Is this really all `sched_yield()` does?
ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/sources/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release/sched_yield.c

EDIT2:(in response to first two comments)
Chris:
Found this source. Its in ASM, not sure what it does.
http://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/libc/arch-arm/syscalls/sched_yield.S?repo=platform--bionic&r=7582a9c119a4e4d0c306996b2513205889a9fb6c

```
ENTRY(sched_yield)
mov ip, r7
ldr r7, =__NR_sched_yield
swi #0
mov r7, ip
movs r0, r0
bxpl lr
b __set_syscall_errno
END(sched_yield)
```

(EDIT2A:Just found this also: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pthreads/+/master/sched_yield.c
uses `Sleep (0);` also.)

I'm new to android/linux stuff. Would I compile with the android libs to get the same results on none android linux? Like the 'strace' suggestion, haven't head of it.

fadden:
I'm porting a multithread c++ application to android/ndk. It uses multiple threads that need to share the cpu time as they can block each other, so deadlocking is a very real possibility that needs to be prevented(hierarchy, is not a issue, api/system calls doing what they are suppose to is). Using a 'sleep' as a workaround seems like it will give me unpredictable behavior and will be cpu cycle expensive.

Comment: You are comparing an implementation atop win32, not a Linux kernel. How about building a simple test on a desktop Linux and strace-ing it (of course threads make that a pain)?

Comment: I was once cautioned by an Android kernel engineer that `sched_yield()` might do nothing at all, so you need to sleep.  But if your sleep duration is too short, the kernel might decide to just let you keep running.  "Too short" could vary from system to system, so you needed to sleep for increasing amounts of time.  I ended up writing a function that started with `sched_yield()` and then did the iterative sleep, but some time later came back to discover that the yield call was effectively sleeping for some absurd duration, which is not at all what I wanted.  So... what are *you* trying to do?

Comment: _uses multiple threads that need to share the cpu time as they can block each other, so deadlocking is a very real possibility_: please accept my sincere condolences.

Comment: Alex, care to be constructive...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sched_yield() is available with the Android NDK (on all supported platforms).
Just include <sched.h> before using it, just like a regular Posix system.

Comment: This seems to be correct, at least with my version on the NDK R9. Perhaps the comments I seen saying `sched_yield()` did nothing were incorrect/out of date. If I encounter issue, I will update. Thank you.